# Quick Sort C++ Implementation (using random pivot) breaks and stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, python, xcode, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to translate my Python Quick Sort implementation into C++ and have written some code. The code seems to break. I am using Xcode for development and all I see, when I compile & run the code is `(lldb)` and the program seems to be stuck in infinite loop.

Please help me find the bug and point out where am I going wrong in the C++ implementation.

**Python Quick Sort Code:**

```
from random import randint

def quickSort(lst):
    if not lst:
        return []
    else:
        pivot_index = randint(0, len(lst) - 1)
        pivot = lst[pivot_index]
        lesser = quickSort([l for i, l in enumerate(lst)
                            if l <= pivot and i != pivot_index])
        greater = quickSort([l for l in lst if l > pivot])
        #print lesser, pivot, greater
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater

print quickSort([3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4, 234, 234, 23, 1234, 24, 132])
```

**C++ Quick Sort Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// simple print function 
void print(int* lesser, int len_lesser, int pivot, int* greater, int len_greater) {
    for (int i=0; i < len_lesser-1; i++) {
        cout << lesser[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << pivot << " ";
    for (int i=0; i < len_greater-1; i++) {
        cout << greater[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

unsigned long long rdtsc(){
    unsigned int lo,hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return ((unsigned long long)hi << 32) | lo;
}

int randint(int len) {
    // srand(time(0));
    srand((unsigned)rdtsc());
    return (rand() % (len) + 0);
}
void quickSort(int* lst, int len) {
    if (lst == NULL) {
        cout << "List Empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        int lesser[] = {};
        int greater[] ={};
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int pivot_index = randint(len);
        int pivot = lst[pivot_index];
        //cout << pivot << endl;
        for (int i=0; i < len-1; i++) {
            if (lst[i] <= pivot && i != pivot_index) {
                lesser[j] = lst[i];
                j = j+1;
            }
        }
        int len_lesser = sizeof(lesser)/sizeof(int);
        quickSort(lesser, len_lesser);

        for (int i=0; i < len-1; i++) {
            if (lst[i] > pivot) {
                greater[j] = lst[i];
                k = k+1;
            }
        }
        int len_greater = sizeof(greater)/sizeof(int);
        quickSort(greater, len_greater);
        print(lesser, len_lesser, pivot, greater, len_greater);
    }

}


int main() {
    int lst[] = {3, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 2, 4, 234, 234, 23, 1234, 24, 132};
    int len = sizeof(lst)/sizeof(int);
    quickSort(lst, len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int lesser[] = {};` is going to create an empty list. How can you then assign within it? You are also incrementing `k` in the second partition but you are indexing with `j`.

Comment: There is a problem with your `randint()` function. You only need to call `srand()` __once__ (usually in `main()`) to seed the random number generator. I also have no idea why you are doing `+0` to the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least one major problem you are not declaring `lesser` nor `greater` to have any size:

```
int lesser[]  = {};
int greater[]  ={};
```

So later on when you try to access them you are going out of bounds:

```
lesser[j] = lst[i];
```

and then later on when take the size it is going to be `0`:

```
int len_lesser = sizeof(lesser)/sizeof(int);
```

The clean solution is to use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and then you don't worry about allocation or size. You should try to enable warnings and always compile with them. In `gcc` when running with `-Wall -W -pedantic` it does not allow me to compile and it tells me:

```
 36:26: error: zero-size array 'lesser'
 37:26: error: zero-size array 'greater'
```

Which tells you right away what is wrong.

Comment: The better solution would be to use `std::vector` otherwise you will have to worry about dynamically allocating you arrays and all the fun that goes with that

Answer (score 4):

In `C++` the arrays you declare are not dynamic. You will either have to use `std::vector` or allocate data dynamically. Otherwise these calls(In the function quickSort):

```
lesser[j] = lst[i];
```

Are accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you can show an example of how to dynamically allocate data to an array with context to my code. I am confused on how to declare and define a dynamic array(Empty) in C++.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar you can not just declare it. In C++ you have to manually manage the allocation and deallocation of dynamic arrays. So a way easier(and better in my opinion) solution is to use an std::vector.